# How to rotate the text correctly to vertically in react native

Tags: android, react-native, expo

The problem is even I rotate the text the layout still getting the width of length of the text

[image: Output]

I tried to rotate the text using this code:

```
style={{transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }]
```

What I'm expecting is to achieve this layout even the text is not the same of their length:

[image]

Comment: You can use `translateX` by about half textWidth plus `translateY` for fine adjustment. Get textWidth via `onLayout`. check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69348958/22253691)